AuthenticationTimeout when trying to pair bluetooth headphones
bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:7B:8C:99 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 4C:31:2D:24:DA:15 4C-31-2D-24-DA-15
[NEW] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 Glove80
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -43
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -52
[NEW] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 58-2E-DE-34-97-F1
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -43
[NEW] Device 64:16:59:3E:8A:89 64-16-59-3E-8A-89
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -52
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -44
[NEW] Device 79:A9:AE:4E:99:77 79-A9-AE-4E-99-77
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -53
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -85
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -45
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -93
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -85
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -94
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -86
[NEW] Device 88:C9:E8:24:E5:38 WH-1000XM5
[NEW] Device EC:FA:5C:7E:09:88 Android TV
bluetoothctl^[[A^[[A^[[A[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -53
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -45
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -53
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -44
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -94
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -53
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -44
[CHG] Device 64:16:59:3E:8A:89 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 64:16:59:3E:8A:89 ManufacturerData Value:
  10 07 7e 1f 37 ad a3 7c 18                       ..~.7..|.
[CHG] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 RSSI: -86
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -52
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -44
[CHG] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 RSSI: -52
^Coz@oz-MS-7B86:~$ bluetoothctl pair 88:C9:E8:24:E5:38
Attempting to pair with 88:C9:E8:24:E5:38
[CHG] Device 88:C9:E8:24:E5:38 Connected: yes
[DEL] Device EC:FA:5C:7E:09:88 Android TV
[DEL] Device 79:A9:AE:4E:99:77 79-A9-AE-4E-99-77
[DEL] Device 58:2E:DE:34:97:F1 58-2E-DE-34-97-F1
[DEL] Device 64:16:59:3E:8A:89 64-16-59-3E-8A-89
[DEL] Device FB:90:16:58:83:D7 Glove80
[DEL] Device 4C:31:2D:24:DA:15 4C-31-2D-24-DA-15
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout

Tried trusting first and restarting bluetooth service  but it also does not work. Here is the journalctl -u bluetooth.service output:
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Starting SDP server
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: src/adapter.c:reset_adv_monitors_complete() Failed to reset Adv Monitors: Failed (0x03)
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Failed to clear UUIDs: Failed (0x03)
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
mar 20 17:34:03 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.94 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
mar 20 17:37:15 oz-MS-7B86 bluetoothd[72820]: Pair device failed: Timeout (0x08)

As a sidenote I'm dual booting on my machine with Windows 10

If you are on Ubuntu Desktop, use the built-in Bluetooth. There may also be a hardware error:

Do you have a Bluetooth adapter/card?
Is it installed correctly, or is the machine dusty?
Have you tried with other Bluetooth devices?

Otherwise, it may be a driver error.

I do have a bluetooth adapter that works when I boot windows 10. My phone is not working as well(getting a notification on my phone about pairing attempt but failes when I accept). Using blueman-manager fails with br-connection-unknown

My phone is not working as well
Try to get some cheap or low-end Earbuds, then connect to them. If it works, then it is an error with the earbuds, otherwise, it is an error with your phone/pc.
